# How to echo "no results" message when no search results are found in MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql, dreamweaver, mysql-num-rows

I have a mysql keyword search on my website and it works fine. The problem is when someone searches a keyword I haven't added, nothing shows up on the results page. Instead of nothing showing up I would like to have a no results were found message. I was told I have to use this code:

```
<?php 
if (mysql_num_rows($rs_main) == 0) {
    echo "No records found.";
}
?>
```

But I've been trying to implement that code within my code for the last couple of days and for some reason I can't get it to work. It would greatly appreciated if someone could show me where and how to properly implement the code above within my code to solve my problem, thanks in advance.

Here's my code so you can better understand my problem

```
<?php
function buildNavigation($pageNum_Recordset1,$tot… | ",$max_links=10, $show_page=true)
{
                GLOBAL $maxRows_Recordset1,$totalRows_Recordset…
    $pagesArray = ""; $firstArray = ""; $lastArray = "";
    if($max_links<2)$max_links=2;
    if($pageNum_Recordset1<=$totalPages_R… && $pageNum_Recordset1>=0)
    {
        if ($pageNum_Recordset1 > ceil($max_links/2))
        {
            $fgp = $pageNum_Recordset1 - ceil($max_links/2) > 0 ? $pageNum_Recordset1 - ceil($max_links/2) : 1;
            $egp = $pageNum_Recordset1 + ceil($max_links/2);
            if ($egp >= $totalPages_Recordset1)
            {
                $egp = $totalPages_Recordset1+1;
                $fgp = $totalPages_Recordset1 - ($max_links-1) > 0 ? $totalPages_Recordset1  - ($max_links-1) : 1;
            }
        }
        else {
            $fgp = 0;
            $egp = $totalPages_Recordset1 >= $max_links ? $max_links : $totalPages_Recordset1+1;
        }
        if($totalPages_Recordset1 >= 1) {
            #    ------------------------
            #    Searching for $_GET vars
            #    ------------------------
            $_get_vars = '';            
            if(!empty($_GET) || !empty($HTTP_GET_VARS)){
                $_GET = empty($_GET) ? $HTTP_GET_VARS : $_GET;
                foreach ($_GET as $_get_name => $_get_value) {
                    if ($_get_name != "pageNum_Recordset1") {
                        $_get_vars .= "&$_get_name=$_get_value";
                    }
                }
            }
            $successivo = $pageNum_Recordset1+1;
            $precedente = $pageNum_Recordset1-1;
            $firstArray = ($pageNum_Recordset1 > 0) ? "<a href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?pageNum_Record… :  "$prev_Recordset1";
            # ----------------------
            # page numbers
            # ----------------------
            for($a = $fgp+1; $a <= $egp; $a++){
                $theNext = $a-1;
                if($show_page)
                {
                    $textLink = $a;
                } else {
                    $min_l = (($a-1)*$maxRows_Recordset1) + 1;
                    $max_l = ($a*$maxRows_Recordset1 >= $totalRows_Recordset1) ? $totalRows_Recordset1 : ($a*$maxRows_Recordset1);
                    $textLink = "$min_l - $max_l";
                }
                $_ss_k = floor($theNext/26);
                if ($theNext != $pageNum_Recordset1)
                {
                    $pagesArray .= "<a href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?pageNum_Record…
                    $pagesArray .= "$textLink</a>" . ($theNext < $egp-1 ? $separator : "");
                } else {
                    $pagesArray .= "$textLink"  . ($theNext < $egp-1 ? $separator : "");
                }
            }
            $theNext = $pageNum_Recordset1+1;
            $offset_end = $totalPages_Recordset1;
            $lastArray = ($pageNum_Recordset1 < $totalPages_Recordset1) ?  "<a href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?pageNum_Record… : "$next_Recordset1";
        }
    }
    return array($firstArray,$pagesArray,$lastArray…
}
?>
<?php require_once('Connections/theconnect.php… ?>
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_strin… ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
   }
  return $theValue;
}
}
$maxRows_Recordset1 = 5;
$pageNum_Recordset1 = 0;
if (isset($_GET['pageNum_Recordset1'])) {
  $pageNum_Recordset1 = $_GET['pageNum_Recordset1'];
}

$startRow_Recordset1 = $pageNum_Recordset1 * $maxRows_Recordset1;

$colname_Recordset1 = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['textfield'])) {
  $colname_Recordset1 = $_GET['textfield'];
}
```

Comment: You're not using the code you said you were told to use... where have you been *trying to use it?

Comment: $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
 <?php 
if (mysql_num_rows($rs_main) == 0) {
    echo "No records found.";
}
?>

$maxRows_Recordset1 = 5;

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using Dreamweaver, just add a Show Region if Recordset Empty command and put the "No search results found" message in it.